# ElasticSearch 5.5 SearchScript

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-java-api

I am in the process of implementing a custom native `SearchScript` that produces a certain score at query execution. Given a term `x` the script should calculate a similarity metric against the set of documents within an index. The search script should be compiled and executed using a `ScriptEngineService` instance. The problem is however that given a field that has been defined explicitly using the mapping endpoint, the field cannot be found within the segment.

```
@Override
public Function<Map<String,Object>,SearchScript> compile(String scriptName,  String scriptSource, Map<String, String> params) {
  if ("script".equals(scriptSource)) {
    return p -> new SearchScript() {
      final String field;
      final String term;

      {
        field = p.get("field").toString();
        term = p.get("term").toString();
      }

      @Override
      public LeafSearchScript getLeafSearchScript(LeafReaderContext context) throws IOException {
        PostingsEnum postings = context.reader().postings(new Term(field), PostingsEnum.PAYLOAD);
          if (postings == null) {
            // The field has not been found within the segment.
            return () -> 0;
          }
```

Any hint onto why no documents containing the given field cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible: postings are per-term while here you are trying to fet postings for an entire field. You should do `context.reader().postings(new Term(field, term), PostingsEnum.PAYLOAD)`.